# Should I use MySQL Lock Table or there exists better solution?

Tags: python, mysql, locking, multiprocessing

I'm working on a multiprocessed application, and each process sometimes executes the following code:

```
db_cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM prqueue;")

for record in db_cursor.fetchall():
    if record[0]:
        db_cursor.execute("DELETE FROM prqueue WHERE id='%s'" % record[0]);
        db_connector.commit()
```

And I'm facing the following problem: there may be a situation, when two processes take the same maximum value, and both try to delete this value. Such situation is not acceptable in the context of my application, each value must be taken (and deleted) only by one process.

How can I achieve this? Is table locking while taking the maximum and deleting absolutely necessary, or there is another, nice way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider simulating record locks with `GET_LOCK()`;

Choose a name specific to the op you want locking. e.g. `'prqueue_max_del'`.

Call `SELECT GET_LOCK('prqueue_max_del',30)` to lock the name `'prqueue_max_del'`.. it will return 1 and set the lock if the name becomes available, or return 0 if the lock is not available after 30 seconds (the second parameter is the timeout).

Use `SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('prqueue_max_del')` when you are finished.

You will have to use the same names in each transaction and calling `GET_LOCK()` again in a transaction will release the previously set lock.

Beware; As only the abstract name is locked, all other processes not using this method and abstract name will be able to savage your table independently.

[**`GET_LOCK()` docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)